# Visual studio, Xamarin, WebView

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm making application for android using Visual Studio and Xamarin but I have problem with WebView when I create a WebView and try to see it in android emulator i get an error:

Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView

Anybody knows where is problem?

The Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";    
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:minWidth="25px" 
    android:minHeight="25px"> 

    <WebView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/webView1" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please include the Layout file (XML) for the activity that contains the WebView. The code for the activity that inflates the layout would be much appreciated.

Comment: @arnfada Hi, I created just simple WebView to make a test, and the same error appears here is he xml code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView1" />
</LinearLayout>

Comment: First thing first, there is a semicolon at the end of the `xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";` that shouldn't be there.
Now, when you run the project. What is the full error description? @Yupi

Comment: @arnfada
I accidentally input semicolon, there is no in my project, I don't know can I here input picutres but I mada a screecapture of error and you can look it on my dropbox here is the link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xkjitv7kra3zz0v/Error.png?dl=0

Note that I remove number 1 from webWiew in xml and in c# so you don't get counfesd by that! Because in picture webView is without number 1. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

After trying out the Layout xml the compiler throws an error becouse of a semicolon at the end of `xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";`. If you remove that the layout should build.

Another thing is that the url in `xmlns:android` attribute is missing `http://` in front of the url. Without that the inflater doesn't understand the attributes correctly.

Here is a fixed Layout for you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:minWidth="25px" 
    android:minHeight="25px"> 

    <WebView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/webView1" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Nope, the same error appears. :/ You have the picture of error in my previuos comment

Comment: Unless you provide me with the actual xml layout and the actual code, there is not much more I can do for you.

Comment: @Yupi, what type of emulator are you using?

Comment: I copied code and paste that you put, but it doesn't work, always the same thing. I think that problem is not in code!
Galaxy Nexus Android 5.0. 1.API 21, I tried to change API level and emulator but same thing, I think that only I can do is to try reinstal Visual Studio